# VB.NET WinForms ListView Question

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I have a ListView with 3 columns, how do I add specified text to the specified column I want? I've looked at the ..Add function, but it doesn't take the column index.. Thanks!

Comment: It might help if you added the code that you already have (where you create the columns for the ListView)

Comment: Well I do it via the GUI Builder in Microsoft Visual Studio. So the code is auto generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim item as New ListViewItem(new String(){"One","Two","Three"})
ListView1.Items.Add(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

ListViewItem has a SubItems property that you can use to set the text of a specified column.